# Pycharm + Black with Formatting on Auto-save by Running a Script

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to write a Python script that will install **Black**(code formatter), and do changes in Pycharm settings to run Black on Autosave and add it to external tools(I am using Linux). I didn't know how to start, and what kind of code to write.

For my local machine, I do it manually, but needed to not do it manually and run the script and it does all the needed steps. As people working on the project not only me, we all need to have the same formatting configurations, so need to have a python script for that.

Comment: What black? color theme?

Comment: whatever its; you can copy your config file of file and send to your team [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/setting-up-your-project.html)

Comment: Sorry, didn't mention the Black I mean code formatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with update xml file of tools in pycharm, and add tool you want.

> Here is function in python

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def add_external_tool(tool_name, command):

    your_version = "2023.1.2" # Put your pycharm version here

    # Path to the tools.xml file
    tools_file = fr"~/.PyCharm{your_version}/config/tools/tools.xml"
    
    # Load the XML file
    tree = ET.parse(tools_file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    
    # Create a new <tool> element
    tool = ET.SubElement(root, 'tool')
    tool.set('name', tool_name)
    tool.set('description', 'My custom tool') # Your description for tool
    
    # Create the <exec> element with the command
    exec_element = ET.SubElement(tool, 'exec') # Change it as you want
    exec_element.text = command
    
    # Save the modified XML back to the file
    tree.write(tools_file)

# Usage
add_external_tool('black', 'which black')
```

you can modify code as you want was reading to get more information on how to setup [black formatter](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/integrations/editors.html)